# Is Apache mod_rewrite working without FQDN, instead with temporary URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As noted in title, is Apache mod_rewrite working and is it fully functional without using FQDN, (domain name), instead with temporary URL?

Like using host IP address and username?

```
192.186.23.12/~user1
```

And using username as RewriteBase:

```
RewriteBase /~user1/
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is not dependent upon FQDN

Comment: @anubhava I have a situation where it works, but in some documentation is noted that mod_rewrite works only with FQDN, and I can't find this in Apache 2.4 documentation.